# Noob question: will a slow rig get coins ever?

Tags: bitcoind

So i get that people buy bigger rigs for faster production, but say I put some old junker on as a miner.  it ever get coins or do the "real" miners get all the coins?

Comment: [3 days of mining on a raspberry pi = 0.00000013 BTC](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1abb3g/citizens_of_rbitcoin_i_present_3_days_of_mining/)

Answer (score 0):

If you join a mining pool, like Slush or Deepbit, you will still get a tiny revenue. On a regular computer (with none of that GPU/FPGA/ASIC stuff), you get 0.7-1.5 MHashes per second. You'd get about 0.000007 BTC (just an estimate) every few hours.

Comment: "Profit" isn't the correct word considering all the money spent on electricity.